# apt: mysql-client and mysql-server not upgraded

Tags: apt, upgrade, mysql

since mysql-client and mysql-server got the update to 8.0.33 they are kept back and not upgraded.

```
The following packages have been kept back:
 mysql-client mysql-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Installing mysql-client-8.0 und mysql-server-8.0 doesnt work:

```
[...]
apt install mysql-server-8.0 mysql-client-8.0
[...]
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client-8.0 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
 mysql-server-8.0 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
                    Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.8+1.0.4~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
[...]
```

Und mysql-common has version 8.0.32:

```
apt-cache policy mysql-common
mysql-common:
  Installed: 8.0.32-1ubuntu18.04
  Candidate: 8.0.32-1ubuntu18.04
  Version table:
 *** 8.0.32-1ubuntu18.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Any solution without completely deleting and reinstalling everything?

Thanks!

** update1

I'm running 20.04.6 LTS. I've updated it about half a year ago from 18.04 to 20.04.

```
lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
```

And my apt sources are all from ubuntu.com archives except the php packages (ondrej).

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I’m seeing two versions of Ubuntu in the output: 18.04 and 20.04. Could you [edit] your question to include the actual version of Ubuntu that you’re running as well as whether these are stock versions of MySQL that you have installed or whether they’re from a third-party repository? This will make it easier to offer the correct solution 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages **mysql-client &  mysql-server** have unmet dependencies and/or is broken.

In order to fix this,

Follow the steps( *Requires reinstall of mysql-client and mysql-server and this is what I did to fix this issue in my system*)

First fix the unmet dependency problem by using aptitude(package manager)

```
sudo apt install aptitude

sudo aptitude install mysql-server

sudo aptitude install mysql-client
```

Accept the confirmation on the last two steps to remove these conflicting packages.

Now both `mysql-client` and`mysql-server` will be removed. Perform an update.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Install **mysql-client**:

```
sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0
```

Install **mysql-server:**

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Run `sudo systemctl start mysql.service`.

If it says `Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service is masked.`

`mysql.service` needs to be unmasked using `sudo systemctl unmask mysql.service`

Now run `sudo systemctl start mysql.service` again.

Check the status of mysql.service using `sudo systemctl status mysql.service`

It should display **Active: active (running)**

This should fix it. Hope it helps!

Comment: that worked out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @provil I'm glad to hear that your issue was resolved successfully! In order to help others who may have a similar problem, please consider marking the solution as accepted. This way, others can benefit from your experience and find a solution more easily. Thank you for sharing your experience with the community!

Comment: I hope now it's correctly flagged :-) Thanks again.